# Cordova App in Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova

I'm testing an application but getting the following errors from Visaul Studion. I have no idea what it is. it's no problem to debug te solution but when I release for an android device I get the errors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a proper certificate for the release configuration? Are you using Visual Studio 2017 with the default Cordova 6.3.1 toolset? You should try with the external Android SDK, or upgrade your Cordova CLI to 7.1.0 and cordova-android 6.3.0. Check out **[this guide](https://www.andreszsogon.com/visual-studio-2017-and-apache-cordova-mobile-apps/#visual_studio_android_sdk)** to find out how to switch the toolset in Visual Studio 2017, because the select drop-down from config.xml designer view will not save your setting.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community. I did the installation with Visual Studio installer. For example, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/first-steps/installation?view=toolsforcordova-2017.
I installed Android SDK and Google Android Emulator

Comment: Cordova 6.3.1 toolset
JavaScript and TypeScript language support
TypeScript 2.3 SDK
JavaScript ProjectSystem and Shared Tooling
JavaScript diagnostics
Mobile development with JavaScript core features

Comment: Try changing to the Cordova 7.1.0 CLI as explained [here](https://www.andreszsogon.com/visual-studio-2017-and-apache-cordova-mobile-apps/#visual_studio_android_sdk), the CLI 6.3.1 is too old now. Or 6.5.0 if you cannot make 7.1.0 work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have cyrillic char in your file name in asset folder ?

You cannot have other char than [a-z0-9_.] on your cordova folder and sub folder.

Answer (score 0):

One of my pictures (café.png) had an apostrophe or prime sign. 
So I changed it and now it works.